# Sheaf Theory, Bredon: Pg 4, (e)

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am reading Bredon's Sheaf Theory. After defining a Sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ over a space $X$ the author has stated some basic properties. I am stuck with the following statement:

**Problem:**

For any two sections $s \in \mathcal{A}(U)$ and $t \in \mathcal{A}(V)$, $U$ and $V$ open, then the set $W:= \{x \in U \cap V: s(x) = t(x)\} \subseteq X$ is open in $X$. Further, if $\mathcal{A}$ is Hausdorff then $W$ is closed in $X$.

I have thought about it in the following direction:

1. Since $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$, $s(U)$ and $t(V)$ are open in $\mathcal{A}$.
2. Since $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism, we have that $\pi: \mathcal{A} \to X$ is an open map.
3. $s(W) = t(W)$. If $s(W)$ is open in $\mathcal{A}$, then $\pi(s(W)) = W$ becomes open in $X$. Therefore proving $s(W)$ is open in $\mathcal{A}$ does the job.

Is there some other way to prove the above claim? Or can we prove that $s(W)$ is open in $\mathcal{A}$? Please provide me with some hints, so that I can proceed.

Comment: It looks like p. (2) should be "$\pi$ is local homeomorphism".

Comment: @dsh Yes. Since $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism, $\pi$ is an open map. That is why I wrote $\pi$ is open. I felt maybe we will need the fact that $\pi$ is open to prove this. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: It was a hint: $s$ and $t$ are local homeomorphisms right inverse to $\pi.$